# add grouped_by_column as new column after using group by using pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a table with 2 column (time,avg of AQI) , and time is the group_by factor.

and unfortunately output don't set time as a column and in another way I need (10,2) shape but I receive (10,1)
please help me,what should I do?

in below code # shows answers for each print
take care that aqi_data is *'DataFrame'*

```
aqi_data=aqi_data2
print(aqi_data.shape)
#(341940, 7)
date_group = aqi_data.groupby("Date").mean().head(10)
print(date_group.shape)
#(10,1)
dates=date_group.sort_values('AQI').head(10)
print(dates.shape)
#(10,1)
```

and lets see this table:(I need both Date and AQI as header)

```
             AQI
Date    
2018-01-10  34.187120
2018-01-09  37.114873
2018-01-05  37.421225
2018-01-06  37.507841
2018-01-04  38.002427
2018-01-02  38.207010
2018-01-08  38.323210
2018-01-01  38.429612
2018-01-07  38.630303
2018-01-03  40.975699
```

Comment: Try: `date_group=aqi_data.groupby("Date").mean().reset_index()`

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks but i received this error then:
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reaset_index'
+ i edit my question and added 'dataframe' then

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo, `reset_index` not `reaset_index`.

Comment: yes, it worked, thanks a lot